# how to use JSON.stringify and json_decode() properly

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, stringify

Im trying to pass a mulitidimensional Javascript array to another page on my site by:

- using JSON.stringify on the array
- assigning the resultant value to an input field
- posting that field to the second page
- using json_decode on the posted value
- then var_dump to test
- (echo'ing the posted variable directly just to see if it came through
  at all)

**Javascript on page one:**

```
var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(fullInfoArray);
document.getElementById('JSONfullInfoArray').value= JSONstr;
```

**php on page two:**

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]);
var_dump($data);

echo($_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]);
```

The echo works fine but the var_dump returns NULL

What have I done wrong?

---

**This got me fixed up:**

```
$postedData = $_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"];
$tempData = str_replace("\\", "",$postedData);
$cleanData = json_decode($tempData);
var_dump($cleanData);
```

Im not sure why but the post was coming through with a bunch of "\" characters separating each variable in the string

Figured it out using `json_last_error()` as sugested by Bart which returned `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

Comment: Check the content of `$_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]`. If something doesn't parse `json_code` will just return `null`. Also use `json_last_error()` to try and find what went wrong.

Comment: A little bit HTML of the form would help too. Look into the request using your browser's inspector, do you see what you expect?

Comment: @Bart see edit above, you got me where I needed to be, throw up an answer and Ill accept it :), thank you very much

Comment: The answer in here worked for me (and all the other 'answers' below didn't!).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to check the contents of `$_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]`. If something doesn't parse `json_decode` will just return `null`. This isn't very helpful so when `null` is returned you should check `json_last_error()` to get more info on what went wrong.

Answer (score 61):

When you save some data using JSON.stringify() and then need to read that in php. The following code worked for me.

```
json_decode( html_entity_decode( stripslashes ($jsonString ) ) );
```

Thanks to @Thisguyhastwothumbs

Comment: Ok, this is like the right answer and what I was looking for. Saved me a couple of hours of disgusting trial and error.

Comment: Thanks this is work for me!!! ... In $request["reporthead"] data as string which is from javascript $tempData = \html_entity_decode(stripslashes ($request["reporthead"]));
                    $reportheaddata = json_decode($tempData, true);

Answer (score 35):

When you use JSON stringify then use html_entity_decode first before json_decode.

```
$tempData = html_entity_decode($tempData);
$cleanData = json_decode($tempData);
```

Comment: worth noting in wp I used the above with stripslashes within the html_entity_decode to make work :

Answer (score 11):

None of the other answers worked in my case, most likely because the JSON array contained special characters.  What fixed it for me:

**Javascript (added encodeURIComponent)**

```
var JSONstr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fullInfoArray));
document.getElementById('JSONfullInfoArray').value = JSONstr;
```

**PHP (unchanged from the question)**

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]);
var_dump($data);

echo($_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]);
```

Both echo and var_dump have been verified to work fine on a sample of more than 2000 user-entered datasets that included a URL field and a long text field, and that were returning NULL on var_dump for a subset that included URLs with the characters `?&#`.

Comment: I also had to use `urldecode` on PHP for it to work properly.

Comment: As @Albion points out, the string needs to be URI decoded before `json_decode` is invoked. `json_decode(urldecode($_POST["JSONfullInfoArray"]));`

Answer (score 8):

```
stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(JSON_DATA))
```

Comment: I am not sure why `htmlspecialchars()` must there. It will convert the quote character ( `"` ) to `&quot;` which is mean can't be processed by `json_decode()`. I am sure `JSON` format must be something like `{"key":"value"}`, but by using `htmlspecialchars()` it will convert to `{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}` how come `json_decode()` processing it?

Answer (score 3):

```
jsonText = $_REQUEST['myJSON'];

$decodedText = html_entity_decode($jsonText);

$myArray = json_decode($decodedText, true);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how this works, but it worked.

```
$post_data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST['request_key']));
```