# JSON in Php not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem and do not know what the problem is. I have a javascript variable in my html. which is:

```
  var people = '{"names": ["Matthew", "Lucas", "Todd", "Roxie", "Kyle", "Ken", "Gideon"], "surnames": ["Patel", "Lee", "Ingram", "Richter", "Katayanagi", "Katayanagi", "Graves"]}';
```

I parse the variable on one function in my script and use it. Everything works fine.

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(people);
```

But then I need to send the data to a php file, I send it by wrtting the data to a hidden input.

```
 var strObject = JSON.stringify(mydata);


var replaced = strObject.replace(/\//g, '');


oFormObject = document.forms['theForm'];
oFormObject.elements["jsonData"].value = replaced;
```

After which I try to encode it in my decode.php using:

```
$obj = $_POST['jsonData'];



json_decode($obj);
$s = stripslashes($obj);


var_dump($s);
```

But when I do a var_dump($s) I get this output:

```
string(147) "{"names":["Matthew","Lucas","Todd","Roxie","Kyle","Ken","Gideon"],"surnames":["Patel","Lee","Ingram","Richter","Katayanagi","Katayanagi","Graves"]}"
```

Thus, I cannot output the contents in $s.Any suggestions.Please let me know if you need more information. BTW, its a homework assignment and I am stuck with the last section.

Comment: `json_decode` returns the object / array. You need to assign the return to a variable e.g. `$jsOb = json_decode($obj)`

Comment: you need to fetch the json returned from `json_decode($obj)`!

Comment: You want to get the name surname pairs from that??

Comment: This might help you out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986235/how-to-use-json-stringify-and-json-decode-properly You should check the answer with html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0):

try saving json_decode($obj)  to a variable and var_dump that 
something like

```
var $temp = json_decode($obj);
var_dump($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer already is in the comments, but since this is the answer, i just post it as an answer.
you need to work with the return value from `json_decode()`. `json_decode($obj)` doesn't change the content of the variable `$obj` by itself:

```
$obj = $_POST['jsonData'];
$obj = json_decode($obj);
$obj = stripslashes($obj);


var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: @niranjan, when I try it your way nothing gets outputed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for name surname pairs from json , you can try this

```
$a = '{"names": ["Matthew", "Lucas", "Todd", "Roxie", "Kyle", "Ken", "Gideon"], "surnames": ["Patel", "Lee", "Ingram", "Richter", "Katayanagi", "Katayanagi", "Graves"]}';
    $b = json_decode($a);
    $c = $b->names;
    $d = $b->surnames;
    for ($i = 0;$i< count($b->names); $i++){
        echo $c[$i]." ". $d[$i] ."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: It still does not work. when I try $obj = json_decode($obj);
 $obj = stripslashes($obj);
 var_dump($obj); I still get the same output

Comment: do it without stripslashes and replace var_dump() with what i have given there

Comment: when I try it your way nothing gets outputed.

Comment: Can I gv you my .php and .js files.its only two files, test it and see what am I doing wrong because I literally copy pasted your code but it does not work.

Comment: No js files required. Go to http://phpfiddle.org/, select initial code, paste the code and runu can see the output.

Comment: Yes you are right it works.But here is something weird. when I use this code: $obj = $_POST['jsonData'];
echo $obj; i get this output :  {\"names\":[\"Matthew\",\"Lucas\",\"Todd\",\"Roxie\",\"Kyle\",\"Ken\",\"Gideon\"],\"surnames\":[\"Patel\",\"Lee\",\"Ingram\",\"Richter\",\"Katayanagi\",\"Katayanagi\",\"Graves\"]}. But if I change it to this: $obj = $_POST['jsonData'];


$p = json_decode($obj);
echo $p; there is no output. I am missing something dont know what.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my php compiler.I put this code on http://phpfiddle.org/ and I get an output, but when I take it to hotdocks nothing happens. Is this possible. Is there somewhere I can post php code for you to just see?

Comment: Wierd. I compared bot json data in http://text-compare.com/, there is a special character after gideon in names and katayanagi in surnames. And that i what is creating the problem. You can also cross check there.

Comment: can you provide the code where you are encoding the data??

Comment: I saw the code, in view, dont do anything except json.stringify(), remove all other code there for encoding.

Comment: it still outputs nothing. What am I really missing?

Comment: Niranjan May you please have a look at these files and tell me what exactly am I doing wrong. Here are the links : http://www.filedropper.com/script_8   http://www.filedropper.com/index_11   
http://www.filedropper.com/decode... Thanks in advanced.

Comment: change the sendData function like this

Comment: function sendData() {

                var strObject = people;





                oFormObject = document.forms['theForm'];
                oFormObject.elements["jsonData"].value = strObject;

            }