# Set php variable to string

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$rm = json_decode($room_list[0]['room']);
```

and i want to set a variable $string which include the result of echo of above variable.
For Example, IF:

```
echo json_decode($room_list[0]['room'];
```

echos: `Lorem Ipsum <a href="www.google.com>GG</a>.`

i want the string to be:

```
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum <a href="www.google.com>GG</a>.'
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. `json_encode()` returns a value. You can either assign it to a variable, or echo it. Either way, you're assigning or echoing the same thing.

Comment: You need a closing ) on your json_decode

Comment: Not for me because i want a string to search in it with another process. My function get only string..not a variable..

Comment: Have you **tried** `echo $rm;`?

Comment: Your first line sets a PHP variable to the string. What's wrong with that?

Comment: _"i want to set a variable $string which include the result of echo of above variable"_ Makes no sense.

Comment: Because after that $string = json_decode(..) the $string is not a string type. It's just a variable and i cant use it in my search function which accepts only string type..

Comment: You don't understand what you're talking about. Since you can echo it, it must be a string. What do you think `echo` is showing?

Comment: There's no such thing as "just a variable". A variable is a name for a value, and the type goes with the value. Since `json_decode` is returning a string, and you assign that to a variable, the variable contains a string.

Comment: All i am trying to do: When i copy/paste the json field from my db and set  $string = 'content of json' then my search function works. If i have $string = content of json without the '' then it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do this: [how to use JSON.stringify and json_decode() properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986235/how-to-use-json-stringify-and-json-decode-properly)

So basically, take `stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(JSON_DATA))` from that answer and put `$rm =` in front :)

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks!