# Get Value from an html form and put into an array

Tags: php

I have a form and a button with a function that create dynamically a textfield and set the name with an index like below: 
corso_1
corso_2
corso_3

So.. a php function get all the value of this form and add all in an array, so how can i get all the value into the dynamic textfields?

Comment: Have you tried naming them using an array name like `name="myfields[]"`?

Comment: You could go through all $_GET values and pick them by a regex or what would be much easier if you name the fields corso[] corso[] this would result automatically in an array

Comment: I don't understand.
Can you type some code?

Comment: If i set the name of the textfields like this: corso[0], corso[1], corso[2]
The follow php code is not good
`$corsi = array(); 
$while(true){
array_push($corsi, $_POST['corso[$i]'];
}`

Answer (score 0):

just put the all data with jquery in that dynamic textfield.by looping throught `Real_data` array and set index as `Real_data['corso_'+i]` and here `i` is a for loop variable.

& `$('#corso')` is the form id.

hope it helps.

```
  var data = $('#corso').serializeArray();
  var Real_data = {}; //this array is used to store sorted data
  $(data).each(function(i,field){
     Real_data[field.name] = field.value;
  });
```

Comment: But how can get it from php

Comment: are showing that array on same page or on another ..??

Comment: I get the value of the dinamyc textfield and put into an array with php, those values will stored into a DB

Comment: the other theory is that use above snippet with`JSON.stringify()` and remove the `$.each` now store the data in hidden text field and when the user submits the form the hidden text field's value will be sent to php script with post or get and then u can store the data in db.

Comment: i didn't think about it!! Thank you!!

Comment: EDIT : when u catch the data from post or get array then it might need `json_decode() `.

Comment: check out this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986235/how-to-use-json-stringify-and-json-decode-properly) for more info.